# How do i change the width/padding of a p-menu component?

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I have made a menu with primeNG's p-menu component and i wish to shift the items of the menu a bit more to the left. I think i should use padding for that and i tried the following to shift it a few pixels.

```
<p-menu [model]="items" [style]="{minWidth:'18.8em', background: 'white', 
                              padding: .625em 0 0 0}"></p-menu>
```

but this is giving me a syntax error, this is the stack trace:

> [ERROR ->])
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents
>   (compiler.js:22639)
>       at compiler.js:22549
>       at Object.then (compiler.js:206)
>       at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents
>   (compiler.js:22548)

The menu itself looks like this:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: nope, same error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<p-menu>` has 'ui-menu'. Style it in the component stylesheet with

- ::ng-deep

  `::ng-deep .ui-menu {
          padding: .625em 0 0 0
  }`

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dialogue-yw8xie)

- ViewCansulation turned off:

  `import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';`

  ```
  ...
  @Component({
    ...
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
  })
  ```

  `.ui-menu {
          padding: .625em 0 0 0
  }`

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dialogue-ydbgxs)

Comment: this gives no syntax error but doesn't work either. No matter what i fill in, .625em or 1000 em the padding stays the same… I also tried adding !important behind it, no effect.

Comment: ::ng-deep .ui-menu { ?